# How to change the border Bottom of Material-UI <Autocomplete/> if is disable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change the appearance of the autocomplete component provided by MaterialUi when it is disabled.
They propose, I imagine, borderBottom: dotted. I would like it to look like the select, also disabled, that I show in the following example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shtern-7icn9?file=/src/playground.js

I don't know how is the correct way to overwrite the property proposed by MaterialUi.
Any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your main css (for overwrite a rule it must be imported after mui):

```
.MuiInput-underline.Mui-disabled:before {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Daniil, I have tried so hard, without favorable results, that it would already seem almost impossible for me to change that property.
I apologize but I do not understand much how you managed to do it, I started working front-end recently.

Comment: When you use any ui lib you know that comes with css, so allmost all of them we can rewrite because it allows css: `last rule = actual rule`. Мy experience in solving problems not only in frontend helped me